# Parenting self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find a few questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: There were only 9 questions that qualified in the time period our algorithm specifies.

Comment: I've voted based on the overall quality of the question+answers. I'm sure the questions could be edited to appear more attractive to new visitors. If that is important, then "someone" (ahem) needs to put in some time to do this. Looking at _just the titles,_ I think this random selection looks good because we already made an effort to rephrase them.

Comment: I'm putting more emphasis on the question, since that will be the first thing visitors will see, but good answers will influence my opinion as well. However, I'm going to ignore votes, as I don't think that will be the first thing visitors will notice (and hopefully more visitors would mean the votes would change over time!).

Comment: Thanks for your input, everyone! I sincerely appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 4):

[How can I get my strong-willed daughter to stop being so lazy when it comes to chores?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-can-i-get-my-strong-willed-daughter-to-stop-being-so-lazy-when-it-comes-to-c)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1: Well-worded question, excellent answers backed by upvotes.

Comment: +1 I think this is an excellent example of the types of questions that make our site useful and interesting. There are also some good answers, too.

Answer (score 3):

[are there any peer reviewed studies showing the benefits of video games for kids (especially girls)?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4917/are-there-any-peer-reviewed-studies-showing-the-benefits-of-video-games-for-kids)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1: Well-worded question, excellent answers backed by upvotes.

Comment: I'd prefer the question were gender-neutral, but I think it is a great question that will be of interest to a lot of people.

Answer (score 3):

[Any suggestions on how to control yelling and negativity on our part, and also teach my 8 yr old son to not feel so helpless and cry so easily?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/any-suggestions-on-how-to-control-yelling-and-negativity-on-our-part-and-also-t)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1: Good participation, great serious answers backed by upvotes.

Comment: I don't love the question.  I think it is too specific to the behavior of the one child, without really distilling a single question (it's more of a "dear Abby" type scenario). However, there are some fantastic answers there, so +1 from me for the answers.

Comment: My concern is that this is asking too many things at once @Beofett.

Comment: @Aarthi I agree (you managed to state that much more clearly than I was able). However, I feel the answers are so good that they make up for it.

Answer (score 3):

[How concerned should we be about Mice coming into the baby's room?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/how-concerned-should-we-be-about-mice-coming-into-the-babys-room)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1: Simple question, simple answer, moderate number of upvotes show agreement.

Comment: I don't like this question much. There's nothing wrong with the way it is worded; I just find it to be close to what I consider the borderline of "on topic". I like the top answer very much, though.  I always love seeing references and citations in answers!

Comment: +1 I asked it and received helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

[New born seems to be spitting up entire meals. Should I be worried?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/new-born-seems-to-be-spitting-up-entire-meals-should-i-be-worried)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1 (barely) for a good question and a good answer, but almost -1 for low participation.

Comment: +1 I think this is an excellent example of the types of questions that make our site useful and interesting. There are also some good answers, too.

Answer (score 2):

[Ways to find (non-religious) volunteer opportunities for your children?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/ways-to-find-non-religious-volunteer-opportunities-for-your-children)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm voting 0: +1 for a good answer, but -1 for few answers and few votes.

Comment: 0 From me, as well. The question and answers aren't *bad*, but they just don't interest me, and seem (to my biased eyes) like they would have limited overall appeal.

Answer (score 1):

[Teaching a child to navigate bullying (or perceived bullying)](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/teaching-a-child-to-navigate-bullying-or-perceived-bullying)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm voting 0: +1 for a good answer, but -1 for few answers and few votes.

Comment: -1 from me. Everytime I read the title of this question, I think "great question!". Then when I actually read the question, I feel the focus is way too specific. It isn't actually about teaching a child to navigate bullying, but rather one very specific instance of social behavior that incorporates a strong bullying element. To me, the title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

[Choosing a Doctor](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/choosing-a-doctor)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm voting 0: +1 for a good answer, but -1 for the question itself -- is this question even on-topic?

Comment: I disagree with Torben on this one. I really like the question. We put a ton of trust in our doctors (even people like me, who tend to question their professional opinion if I think they're taking shortcuts), and there are a *lot* of bad doctors out there. Given how much time children tend to see doctors (particularly if they need a specialist), I think this is a central question to parenting. I would like to see more answers, but there are some good ones there.

Answer (score -3):

[What is a good compilation of songs in english for children that includes the "classic" ones?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4888/what-is-a-good-compilation-of-songs-in-english-for-children-that-includes-the-c)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: -1: This is actually a request for a specific shopping recommendation and should have been closed.

Comment: -1 from me, as well. Torben is absolutely correct; this should have been closed (I have rectified this oversight).