# Parenting Self-Evaluation: Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**Note:** This evaluation will close on **7 September 2012**, so be sure to vote on the answers by then!

Comment: Will we have these introspections every 3 months?

Comment: maybe you can add the  **below answers to your question**,since providing the list of questions in answers sections will cause users feel vague to read and site to spam ,so that they can comment on respective questions

Comment: I only see 9 answers but the OP says ten. I guess the nine are representative enough for this task.

Comment: @vignesh I believe the reason the list of questions is provided as a series of answers is so that we can vote on each question individually.  That's the best way to provide a concrete metric for them.

Comment: Please, everyone, take note that we are being asked to **comment** on the answers below, as well as voting!

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Eek, I didn't see this! Yes, these happen every 3 months for you guys. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everyone! :)

Answer (score 3):

[How do you encourage a toddler that you suspect may be gifted?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/how-do-you-encourage-a-toddler-that-you-suspect-may-be-gifted)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm obviously a bit biased towards the question, and I posted it because I believe that there is a [significant population](http://giftedissues.davidsongifted.org/BB/) of people interested in parenting questions related to gifted children, yet these questions are under-represented on our site. I think the answers I received were very good, and immediately helpful (in particular "praise hard work rather than natural gifts" is fantastic).

Comment: +1: Well-worded question, good but few answers backed by upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

[How do you teach morals and values in non-religious households?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/how-do-you-teach-morals-and-values-in-non-religious-households)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I couldn't bring myself to vote on this question, nor most of its answers, because, despite the high votes, it is a bit too subjective for my tastes, and most of the answers don't attempt to adhere to our rule regarding citations or personal experience being required to back up an answer. Anecdotally, I did agree with a number of answers, despite not being willing to vote for them.

Comment: +1 for a question that really got the crowd active: 12 answers? Wow! Also note that all answers are framed positively and constructively. There's no god-bashing and no atheist-bashing. This is sensible grown-up helpfulness.

Comment: I'm a bit biased, but I really liked this question and the quality of the answers. As @Torben said - good clean discussion.

Answer (score 2):

[What to do when the pinky is the only way to soothe a newborn?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5649/what-to-do-when-the-pinky-is-the-only-way-to-soothe-a-newborn)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1 from me. A good, very basic question a lot of parents are likely to wonder about, and two very good answers that provide useful advice based on personal experience or published reference material.

Answer (score 2):

[How to help my newborn pass gas](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5671/how-to-help-my-newborn-pass-gas)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1. I think the question is okay, but not great (it is clear, and on-topic, but I felt it could have shown more basic research). However, the answers are really exemplary.

Comment: @Beoett: I agree about lack of basic research but I can empathize with the lack of effort considering the baby was 10 days old.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Good point!  I guess I'm far enough removed from that that I have trouble remembering just how hectic those first few days are...

Comment: The answers really ave this one - question is basic, but easily searchable, which is important.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I keep a 14 month old busy at some activity for longer than 3 minutes](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5672/how-can-i-keep-a-14-month-old-busy-at-some-activity-for-longer-than-3-minutes)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1. The answers here are very good, particularly when they reference other related questions here on our site!

Comment: +1: A good basic question, good answers backed by upvotes. The question is not very elaborate but the topic is simple.

Comment: +1 from me - a useful question for new parents, and the answers include real world examples.

Answer (score 1):

[What are the differences between a child who was born vaginally versus via caesarean section?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/what-are-the-differences-between-a-child-who-was-born-vaginally-versus-via-caesa)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: No vote from me.  The question is partially based on a premise that didn't sound particularly likely to me, but the answer (which perhaps unsurprisingly linked to skeptics.se) was solid.

Comment: +1 for a well-phrased and interesting question (there's so much voodoo around different birth methods). There could've been more answers, but the link to Skeptics seems somehow authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

[Retrain toddler to potty?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/retrain-toddler-to-potty)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1.  A good, yet simple, question (I find it to be distinct from the suggested dup due to this being about *re*training after a lapse), with a thorough, informative, and reassuring answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Daughter not saying "mom" even though she can](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/daughter-not-saying-mom-even-though-she-can)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I want to upvote this, because I love the question (we had a very similar issue), but I think the answers are lacking.  One answer is okay, but assumes the root problem without addressing other possible causes.  The other is just too much of a suggestion of "you might try this", rather than anything like an authoritative answer.

Comment: No vote from me: +1 for a good question but -1 for few and relatively poor answers.

Answer (score 0):

[Should my wife pump after feeding to "top her off?"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/should-my-wife-pump-after-feeding-to-top-her-off)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: No vote from me. The question is good, but the answers lack references. One mentions some good external resources, but it would be far better if the answer was self-contained, and included specific citations from one or more reputable sources instead of just suggesting them as further research for the OP.

Comment: No vote from me: +1 for a good question but -1 for few and relatively simple answers.